getAllShipment Function Not Fetching Data from Smart Contract Properly
I'm encountering an issue with my getAllShipment function in my JavaScript code. The function is intended to fetch and map shipment data from a smart contract. However, I'm seeing that only the first two console.log statements (1 and 2) are printed, and the third statement (3) isn't reached.
const getAllShipment = async () => {
    try {
        console.log("1")
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
        const signer = provider.getSigner()
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(ContractAddress, ContractABI, signer)
        
        console.log("2")
        const shipments = await contract.getAllTransactions()
        console.log(shipments)
        console.log("3")
        const allShipments = shipments.map((shipment) => ({
            sender: shipment.sender,
            receiver: shipment.receiver,
            price: ethers.utils.formatEther(shipment.price.toString()),
            pickupTime: shipment.pickupTime.toNumber(),
            deliveryTime: shipment.deliveryTime.toNumber(),
            distance: shipment.distance.toNumber(),
            isPaid: shipment.isPaid,
            status: shipment.status,
        }));

        return allShipments;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Something went wrong", error);
    }
}

Below are the full code:
Tracking.sol:
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.24;

contract Tracking {
    enum ShipmentStatus {
        PENDING,
        IN_TRANSIT,
        DELIVERED
    }

    struct Shipment {
        address sender;
        address receiver;
        uint256 pickupTime;
        uint256 deliveryTime;
        uint256 distance;
        uint256 price;
        ShipmentStatus status;
        bool isPaid;
    }

    mapping(address => Shipment[]) public shipments;
    uint256 public shipmentCount;

    struct TypeShipment {
        address sender;
        address receiver;
        uint256 pickupTime;
        uint256 deliveryTime;
        uint256 distance;
        uint256 price;
        ShipmentStatus status;
        bool isPaid;
    }
    TypeShipment[] typeShipments;

    event ShipmentCreated(
        address indexed sender,
        address indexed receiver,
        uint256 pickupTime,
        uint256 distance,
        uint256 price
    );
    event ShipmentInTransit(address indexed sender, address indexed receiver, uint256 pickupTime);
    event ShipmentDelivered(address indexed sender, address indexed receiver, uint256 deliveryTime);
    event ShipmentPaid(address indexed sender, address indexed receiver, uint256 amount);

    constructor() {
        shipmentCount = 0;
    }

    function createShipment(
        address _receiver,
        uint256 _pickupTime,
        uint256 _distance,
        uint256 _price
    ) public payable {
        require(msg.value == _price, "Payment amount must match the price");

        Shipment memory shipment = Shipment(
            msg.sender,
            _receiver,
            _pickupTime,
            0,
            _distance,
            _price,
            ShipmentStatus.PENDING,
            false
        );

        shipments[msg.sender].push(shipment);
        shipmentCount++;

        typeShipments.push(
            TypeShipment(
                msg.sender,
                _receiver,
                _pickupTime,
                0,
                _distance,
                _price,
                ShipmentStatus.PENDING,
                false
            )
        );

        emit ShipmentCreated(msg.sender, _receiver, _pickupTime, _distance, _price);
    }

    function startShipment(address _sender, address _receiver, uint256 _index) public {
        Shipment storage shipment = shipments[_sender][_index];
        TypeShipment storage typeShipment = typeShipments[_index];

        require(shipment.receiver == _receiver, "Invalid receiver");
        require(shipment.status == ShipmentStatus.PENDING, "Shipment already is in transit");

        shipment.status = ShipmentStatus.IN_TRANSIT;
        typeShipment.status = ShipmentStatus.IN_TRANSIT;

        emit ShipmentInTransit(_sender, _receiver, shipment.pickupTime);
    }

    function completeShipment(address _sender, address _receiver, uint256 _index) public {
        Shipment storage shipment = shipments[_sender][_index];
        TypeShipment storage typeShipment = typeShipments[_index];

        require(shipment.receiver == _receiver, "Invalid rceiver");
        require(shipment.status == ShipmentStatus.IN_TRANSIT, "Shipment not in transit");
        require(!shipment.isPaid, "Shipment already paid.");

        shipment.status = ShipmentStatus.DELIVERED;
        typeShipment.status = ShipmentStatus.DELIVERED;
        typeShipment.deliveryTime = block.timestamp;
        shipment.deliveryTime = block.timestamp;

        uint256 amount = shipment.price;

        payable(shipment.sender).transfer(amount);

        shipment.isPaid = true;
        typeShipment.isPaid = true;

        emit ShipmentDelivered(_sender, _receiver, shipment.deliveryTime);
        emit ShipmentPaid(_sender, _receiver, amount);
    }

    function getShipment(
        address _sender,
        uint256 _index
    )
        public
        view
        returns (address, address, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, ShipmentStatus, bool)
    {
        Shipment memory shipment = shipments[_sender][_index];
        return (
            shipment.sender,
            shipment.receiver,
            shipment.pickupTime,
            shipment.deliveryTime,
            shipment.distance,
            shipment.price,
            shipment.status,
            shipment.isPaid
        );
    }

    function getShipmentCount(address _sender) public view returns (uint256) {
        return shipments[_sender].length;
    }

    function getAllTransactions() public view returns (TypeShipment[] memory) {
        return typeShipments;
    }
}


Tacking.js:
import React, { Children, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Web3Modal from "web3modal";
import { ethers } from "ethers";

// INTERNAL IMPORTS
import tracking from "../Context/Tracking.json"
const ContractAddress = "0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3"
const ContractABI = tracking.abi;
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

// FETCHING SMART CONTRACT
const fetchContract = (signerOrProvider) =>
    new ethers.Contract(ContractAddress, ContractABI, signerOrProvider);

export const TrackingContext = React.createContext();

export const TrackingProvider = ({ children }) => {
    
    // STATE VARIABLE
    const DappName = "Product Tracking Dapp";
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState("");

    const createShipment = async (items) => {
        console.log(items);
        const { receiver, pickupTime, distance, price } = items;

        try {
            const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
            const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
            const provider = new ethers.Web3Provider(connection);
            const signer = provider.getSigner();
            const contract = fetchContract(signer);
            const createItem = await contract.createShipment(
                receiver, 
                new Date(pickupTime).getTime(),
                distance,
                ethers.utils.parseUnits(price, 18),
                {
                    value: ethers.utils.parseUnits(price,18),
                }
            )
            await createItem.wait();
            console.log(createItem);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Something went wrong!", error);
        }
    }

    const getAllShipment = async () => {
        try {
            // const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider()
            // console.log(provider)
            // const contract = fetchContract(provider);
            console.log("1")
            const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
            const signer = provider.getSigner()
            const contract = new ethers.Contract(ContractAddress,ContractABI, signer)
            
            console.log("2")
            await delay(2000)
            const shipments = await contract.getAllTransactions()
            
            // const shipments = [
            //     {
            //         sender: "0xSenderAddress",
            //         receiver: "0xReceiverAddress",
            //         price: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.5"),
            //         pickupTime: ethers.BigNumber.from(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)), // Convert to integer
            //         deliveryTime: ethers.BigNumber.from(Math.floor((Date.now() + 3600) / 1000)), // Convert to integer
            //         distance: ethers.BigNumber.from(100),
            //         isPaid: true,
            //         status: "Delivered",
            //     },
            // ]
            await delay(2000)
            console.log("3")
            const allShipments = shipments.map((shipment) => ({
                sender: shipment.sender,
                receiver: shipment.receiver,
                price: ethers.utils.formatEther(shipment.price.toString()),
                pickupTime: shipment.pickupTime.toNumber(),
                deliveryTime: shipment.deliveryTime.toNumber(),
                distance: shipment.distance.toNumber(),
                isPaid: shipment.isPaid,
                status: shipment.status,
            }));

            return allShipments;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Something went wrong", error);
        }
    }

    const getShipmentsCount = async () => {
        try {
            if (!window.ethereum) return "Install MetaMask";
            const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
                method: "eth_requestAccounts",
            });

            // const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(`https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/ErVq1VJ9pedwYuXG8L_WGfru6tpp-VxV`);
            // const contract = fetchContract(provider);

            const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
            const signer = provider.getSigner()
            const contract = new ethers.Contract(ContractAddress, ContractABI, signer)
            const shipmentsCount = await contract.getShipmentsCount(accounts[0]);
            return shipmentsCount.toNumber();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error:",
                error);
        }
    }

    const completeShipment = async (completeShip) => {
        console.log(completeShip);

        const { receiver, index } = completeShip;
        try {
            if (!window.ethereum) return "Install Metamask";

            const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
                method: "eth_requestAccounts",
            })
            const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
            const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
            const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
            const signer = provider.getSigner();
            const contract = fetchContract(signer);

            const transaction = await contract.completeShipment(
                accounts[0],
                receiver,
                index,
                {gasLimit: 300000,}
            )

            transaction.wait();
            console.log(transaction);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("wrong completeshipent", error);
        }
    }

    const getShipment = async (index) => {
        console.log(index * 1);
        try {
            if (!window.ethereum) return "Install Metamask";

            const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
                method: "eth_requestAccounts",
            })
            // const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(`https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/ErVq1VJ9pedwYuXG8L_WGfru6tpp-VxV`);
            // const contract = fetchContract(provider);

            const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
            const signer = provider.getSigner()
            const contract = new ethers.Contract(ContractAddress, ContractABI, signer)
            const shipment = await contract.getShipment(accounts[0], index * 1);

            const SingleShipment = {
                sender: shipment[0],
                receiver: shipment[1],
                pickupTime: shipment[2].toNumber(),
                deliveryTime: shipment[3].toNumber(),
                distance: shipment[4].toNumber(),
                price: ethers.utils.formatEther(shipment[5].toString()),
                status: shipment[6],
                isPaid: shipment[7],
            }

            return SingleShipment;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Sorry no shipment", error);
        }
    }

    const startShipment = async (getProduct) => {
        const { receiver, index } = getProduct;

        try {
            if (!window.ethereum) return "Install Metamask";

            const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
                method: "eth_requestAccounts",
            });

            const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
            const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
            const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
            const signer = provider.getSigner();
            const contract = fetchContract(signer);
            const shipment = await contract.startShipment(
                accounts[0],
                receiver,
                index * 1
            )

            shipment.wait();
            console.log(shipment);

        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Sorry no shipment", error);
        }
    }

    // CHECK WALLET CONNECTED
    const checkIfWalletConnected = async () => {
        try {
            if (!window.ethereum) return "Tnstall Metamask";

            const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
                method: "eth_requestAccounts",
            })

            if (accounts.length) {
                setCurrentUser(accounts[0]);
            } else {
                return "No account";
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return "not connected";
        }
    }

    // CONNECT THE WALLET
    const connectWallet = async () => {
        try {
            if (!window.ethereum) return "Install Metamask";

            const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
                method: "eth_requestAccounts",
            })
            setCurrentUser(accounts[0]);
        } catch (error) {
            return "Something went wrong";
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        checkIfWalletConnected();
    }, []);

    return (
        <TrackingContext.Provider
            value={{
                connectWallet,
                createShipment,
                getAllShipment,
                completeShipment,
                getShipment,
                startShipment,
                getShipmentsCount,
                DappName,
                currentUser,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </TrackingContext.Provider>
    );
}



Details:

Contract Address and ABI: The ContractAddress and ContractABI are correctly defined and used.
Function getAllTransactions: The function getAllTransactions is expected to return an array of shipment objects.
Error Handling: The catch block is in place to catch any errors, but no specific errors are logged.

Could you help me diagnose why the code isn't reaching the third console.log statement and how I might resolve this issue? I'll provide the contract and full JavaScript code if needed.

if console.log("2") gets executed and console.log("3") does not, that would imply that contract.getAllTransactions() never resolves .. is that a function you wrote?

This is the section:
        console.log("2")
        const shipments = await contract.getAllTransactions()
        console.log(shipments)
        console.log("3")

2 is successfully printed, but 3 does not print at all. This means that you await indefinitely on contract.getAllTransactions() which means that you are awaiting upon multiple transactions and at least one of them is either never finishes, or is just too slow for you to wait for it.
You need to look into what your transactions are, which are the ones that are causing the wait, decide whether it's necessary for you to wait for all the transactions and if some of the transactions can be executed asynchronously, that is, without waiting for it, but, instead, executing a callback when it's done.
Also, look into the transactions and try to optimize them if possible.
Also, think about your strategy. Do you really need to wait for all your transactions? Do all transactions need to finish for your shipments to be retrieved? Are there some transactions perchance that can be scheduled after retrieving the shipments? Is it possible to start the transactions much earlier than needing the shipments to be retrieved, so by the time the shipments are needed they are ready? These are all questions you need to ask yourself. You detected problems in terms of waiting too much. So you will need to think about what takes too much time, what can be improved code-wise, in terms of data representation, scheduling and in your strategy.
